# Undoing one's votes on Stack Exchange

Tags: stack-exchange

I am looking for a program, browser extension or user script, that can undo one's votes on a Stack Exchange website. I'm aware that not all votes can be undone. It shouldn't imply deleting one's account.

Any OS, any license, any browser, any price is fine.

Comment: I suspect that if you ask on Meta, you'll discover that there are scripts for this.

Comment: @CPerkins sounds good, I'll wait a bit more here in case, if no answer I'll ask on meta.

Comment: Are you aware that almost no vote cannot be undone after a short period of time, as long as the post you voted for is not changed?

Comment: @DocBrown Yes  I'm aware that not all votes can be undone.

Comment: "Not all" is quite different from "almost none". What is your usecase?

Comment: @DocBrown The user didn't understand the vote policy.

Comment: And what should such a script be good for if 95% of the votes cannot be changed? Just for the remaining 5%?

Comment: @DocBrown the script will only do what is possible to do.

Comment: Mass unvoting will trigger ragequit scripts and possible mod intervention/penalty box time.

Comment: @DeerHunter Where did you read that mass unvoting triggers ragequit scripts?

Comment: Franck, turns out I was wrong: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199946/are-unupvotes-serial-voting

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Thanks, still interested, but no need to code it just for me, was just in case someone already had worked on it :)